# Flutter 2: Store gradient in ThemeData

Tags: flutter, themes

For a better development I would like to store a gradient which is a part of my main application theme. I would like to store it instead of hardcodding it everytime.

I am implementing a Theme using ThemeData.

```
ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.black,
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
  // somethingToStoreMyGradient
)
```

Is there a way to store a gradient in a `ThemeData` ?

Comment: you need to create your custom à-la theme `Widget` storing whatever data you want

Comment: Ok I will look that and respond to the question when I will have finished

Comment: see how other themes are implemented, for example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c19845a8c3/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip_theme.dart#L42

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html), you can't!
It accepts only Color for the color schemes.

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation but I am hopping for an unknown solution haha